# How to reload iterm plist file?

Tags: macos, iterm, plist

I want to change my iterm background photo in every 10 mins.

So I tried to use cmd `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy` to change the config file `com.googlecode.iterm2.plist`.

And here is my command:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Set :"New Bookmarks":0:"Background Image Location" "/Users/boy/imgs/'$(( $RANDOM % 100 ))'.jpg"' ~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist
```

But it did not work immediately. 
I have to quit my iterm and reopen it, and then the photo changed.

It just seems that the plist file is not loaded immediately after I changed it.

So my question is how to reload the plist file to make my change work immediately?

Comment: You've already discovered how & when plists are loaded - at launch.

Comment: I want to change my background photo every 10 mins. So I am wondering is there a way to reload the config file once I change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the [Dynamic Profiles](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-dynamic-profiles.html) to reload your profiles in time.

1. Add Property List Json

You can create a json file in `~/Library/Application Support/iTerm2/DynamicProfiles` folder. For example, your file is named `profile.json`.

2. Modify the json file.

Use `Dynamic Profile Parent Name` to extends your settings and just modify specified attribution.

```
{
    "Profiles": [
        {
            "Name": "the name of new profile",
            "Guid": "a unique string",
            "Dynamic Profile Parent Name": "Default",
            "Background Image Location": "location of your image"
        }
    ]
}
```

After that, you can see the change of your background image at once.

Comment: This solution solved my problem perfectly. Iterm may not support reloading plist file 
  immediately once it changed. And this is a good way to do it.